# Suppress a warning for all projects in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, suppress-warnings

I've seen answers showing how to suppress a warning for a specific line of code or for a specific project. I don't want that.

I want to suppress a specific warning for *all* of my projects.

(If it matters, the warning is IDE0044. And I'm using C#.)

Comment: You can create a source file in the solution directory with the `[SuppressMessage]` attribute in it. Then include it in each project with "Add Existing File... Add As Link".

Comment: @RonBeyer That's not exactly what I'm looking for, but thanks for the workaround.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A recent update to Visual Studio 2017 (15.7.1) has an option for this now. Under the `Tools->Options` menu, select the `TextEditor->C#->Code Style->General` tab. Under `Field preferences`, there is a `Prefer readonly` option.  Set that to `No`.

[image: Image of the text editor preferences.]

There is also an `editorconfig` setting you can set if you want to check this preference in along side your code, so others who consume your code don't get the warning, but that has to be done on a per solution basis. The `editorconfig` value you would set would be:

```
 dotnet_style_readonly_field = false:none
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`SuppressMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244717.aspx) attribute present under `System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis` namespace like

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA1801:ReviewUnusedParameters", MessageId = "args")]
```

Well as you have edited saying *I want to suppress a specific warning for all of my projects*

You can't do that for a entire project wise AFAIK. But check the linked post once if that helps

[How to suppress code analysis messages for all type members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32357046/how-to-suppress-code-analysis-messages-for-all-type-members)

Comment: Thanks. But that only works for one project. Please correct me if I'm wrong. (I'm not the downvoter, though.)

Comment: @ispiro yes as you have said *specific line of code* see the linked documentation for more information

Comment: @Rahul he did say "specific line of code", but you have the context wrong.

Comment: @mxmissile, not entirely as OP says *how to suppress a warning for a specific line of code or for a specific project*

Comment: Thanks. But @mxmissile is right. I just meant that I've already seen those, and that that is not what I'm looking for. I edited the question to be a little clearer.

Comment: @ispiro don't think you can suppress message likewise and edited the post with the same statement

Comment: See my answer for how to disable this in VS.

Answer (score 5):

You may try to use [Directory.Build.props](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build) adding [NoWarn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj715718.aspx) property for specific warnings. I haven't verified it though.

And as it's said in another answer, it's better to fix the root cause instead of ignoring it.

Answer (score 5):

**To suppress warnings for all projects, you need to create a `.editorconfig` file in a top-level directory.** For example, I have mine in trunk and I commit it to source control so that my colleagues share the same settings.

The settings in this file apply to all projects in trunk and subfolders, unless overridden by another `.editorconfig` file further down the folder tree e.g. you might you have a project specific EditorConfig file in a subfolder which has different settings. See [File hierarchy and precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2019#file-hierarchy-and-precedence) for more details.

### Creating an EditorConfig file

You can use a text editor for this if you just want to change one specific setting. However, Visual Studio can create a `.editorconfig` file with sensible defaults for .NET for you. From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2017):

- Create a new project
- From the menu bar, choose **Project** > **Add New Item**; or press **Ctrl+Shift+A**
- Select the `editorconfig File (.NET)` template to add an EditorConfig file prepopulated with default .NET code style, formatting, and naming conventions

[image]

- Optionally delete the project - we don't really need it

### Visual Studio 2019 - Creating an EditorConfig file from current settings

In Visual Studio 2019, you can instead [create an EditorConfig file from your current settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-styles-and-code-cleanup?view=vs-2019). Just click the following button in the **Options** dialog under `Text Editor > C# > Code Style > General`:

[image]

If you're creating in a text editor you'll probably need this at the top of the file, adjusted as necessary:

```
# Remove the line below if you want to inherit .editorconfig settings from higher directories
root = true

# C# files
[*.cs]
```

### Disabling IDE0044 in the editor config file

To disable IDE0044 specifically, add or change the following setting in the `.editorconfig` file:

```
dotnet_style_readonly_field = false:none
```

(In Visual Studio 2019, you can set the `Prefer readonly` option to `No` under `TextEditor-> C# -> Code Style-> General` in **Options** and then press the `Generate .editorconfig file from settings` button as detailed above).

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add to Stephen's post that his solution with the `.editorconfig` file didn't work out for me without specifying the files I want to apply the rule to. For example, and given that I want to apply a rule to all the test files and that I follow a naming convention in which these end up with "Tests.cs", I have managed to ignore the CA1707 rule in those files by using the following rule:

```
[*Tests.cs]
dotnet_diagnostics.CA1707.severity = none
```

More information on my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61091407/1198379)

Comment: I didn't post my complete file as I made it with VS and it's large, but I do indeed have something similar at the top (`[*.cs]`). Turns out it's important! I've added the info to my answer for people who are making the config file manually. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I think there is a small typo: it should be dotnet_diagnostic and not dotnet_diagnostics. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/configuration-files

Answer (score -3):

IDE0044 is "add readonly modifier" so why not just add the modifier?

Warnings are telling you that you're doing something wrong, but the app will compile.

It's best to have zero warnings in an ideal world.

Comment: Because in some situations readonly is not the best modifier to use (on arrays, for example, because arrays can be modified even if that particular reference can't be).  Also, there are some situations where it's perfectly legitimate and desirable to reassign fields, and IDE0044 is still reported on them.

Comment: I disagree.  Even on an array, setting to read only means you are not going to get rid of the entire array.  If got get this warning, it's telling you this it's completely safe to.  With regards to the changing of arrays.  Whilst an array of list is great inside a class, you should only return a read only collection to protect your array

Comment: Sure, if you also go the route of making every field access be a propery access instead. There are non-array reasons to suppress the message, as well; regardless of whether you agree with them, the concept is that it's a style warning, not a compiler warning. It's an IDExxxx warning, not a CSxxxx warning. You may reasonably disagree with my dispute of its necessity, and I may reasonably disagree with your perception of its universal appropriateness. People can reasonably disagree, and reasonably desire to disable the warning; this question is about doing so as a matter of their own policy.

Comment: In a non-ideal, i.e. real, world, it's very easy to get stuck with a project with nearly 2k warnings, mostly unused variables etc. I'm not fixing all those, and they can safely be suppressed.

Comment: Well many people use VS for unity c# programming. In which u can add a SerializeField attribute to show and modify variables in the inspector which VS is unable to detect and this warning gets really annoying.

Comment: Should any switch-case construction have a default section? Are you sure?