# IDE0044 (Make field readonly) depending on target framework?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-standard

Consider this code:

```
class C
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenRegistration _ctr;
    public C(CancellationToken t) => _ctr = t.Register(...);
    private void Bla() => _ctr.Dispose();
}
```

Resharper warns (correctly, I think?) about a "possibly impure struct method called on readonly variable: struct value always copied before invocation".

But when `readonly` is removed from the declaration, the compiler may or may not emit a "IDE0044: Make field read only" message. Interestingly, it does so if .NET Standard 2.1 is targeted, but not if 2.0 (didn't check other targets).

Assuming `Dispose()` *is* impure (it might release the internal reference to the `CancellationTokenSource` and/or the callback), then I'd prefer it to be called on the field rather than a copy thereof, so no `readonly`.

Either way I have to suppress some message/warning, which is annoying.

Question: can anybody explain why the C# compiler does or doesn't emit the IDE0044 message depending on the target framework? Was there a fundamental change in the rules when/if methods of `readonly` structs are called on a copy?

Comment: IDE0044 suffers from multiple accuracy issues.  Disabling it so you'll never have to look at it again only takes [10 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50399422/suppress-a-warning-for-all-projects-in-visual-studio).