# How to tell the compiler that it's ok to have an uninitialized non nullable property

Tags: c#

i have enabled Nullable Reference Types in my old project and i'm new to this concept.

i have a data model like this :

```
 public class AddClientInput
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
    }
```

this compiler show this warning message :

Warning CS8618  Non-nullable property 'Name' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor.

in typescript i can supress the warning by adding the "null forgiving operator"

```
 class AddClientInput
    {
       Code!: string;
       Name!: string;
    }
```

How can i do something similar to this in c# (without initializing  the variable) ?

Comment: I think youve maybe misunderstood the point of nullable ref types. With it on, a reference type (ie, `string`) not marked nullable with `?` must be initialised

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppress a warning for all projects in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50399422/suppress-a-warning-for-all-projects-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
public string Code {get;set;} = null!;
```

Comment: nullable reference types - if you want a string to be nullable it needs to be `string?`

Comment: That's not how I understand the question. It should be non nullable and suppress the warning. Then that's the solution.

Comment: _"i have enabled Nullable Reference Types in my old project"_ line 1

Comment: "How to tell the compiler that it's ok to have an uninitialized non nullable property" :-)

Comment: Fine then your type must be declared as `string?` in your answer then it makes sense. But you cant initialiser a non-nullable string to null.

Comment: My code is not initializing anything, it's the way to suppress the error warning. That's that was asked.

Comment: Absolutely you can initialize a non-nullable string (or other reference type) to null, you just have to tell the compiler to shut up about it, which is what this answer shows how to do. Personally I don't think this is a good idea to do, because you're sort of removing value from the whole concept, but this is what was asked.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, yes i believe it's a bad idea too , but what's your solution if you want to create just a data model class or an entity framework model... ?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what behavior you want to achieve. I would **not recommend** doing this:

```
public string Code {get;set;} = null!;
```

Here we say "This property is not supposed to have nulls", and at the same time we say "hey compiler, I know there is an issue with that code (we don't have to provide a value for the property `Code` when we create an instance of that type), but please close your eyes on that".

A better way would be either records with positional syntax:

```
public record AddClientInput(string Code, string Name);
```

or if it's a class that can't be converted into a record, then a constructor:

```
public record AddClientInput
{
    public string Code{ get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public AddClientInput(string code, string name)
    {
        Code = name;
        Name = email;
    }
}
```

or `required` keyword introduced in c#11:

```
public class AddClientInput
{
    public required string Code { get; set; }
    public required string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have told the compiler that this property will *never* be null. So you *must* initialise it. I usually go with an empty string for string types in this case.

```
public string Code { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

If you want the string to be nullable you must declare it as such

```
public string? Code { get; set; } // Compiler wont complain now
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make the property nullable by adding a `?`

```
Public string? Code { get; set; }
```

On the other hand you could

```
Public string Code { get; set; } = default;
```

If you don't want this, you can disable this by deleting the below line from the `csproj` file or setting it as disable. By default value is disable.

```
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
```